# SpeechSynthesisUtterance list of languages?

Tags: javascript

I'm using `SpeechSynthesisUtterance` in javascript and cannot find a list of the languages supported.

Does anybody know how to get a list of the languages containing the code and the name of the language?

example. 
English-US  en-US
Japanese    ja-JA

Answer (score 9, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesisUtterance/lang

Review this. But to make a very long story short, the language setter/getter returns a BCP-47 language tag. [List here](http://www.lingoes.net/en/translator/langcode.htm). No guarantee that any are particularly supported per a browser, as a comprehensive list of supported values doesn't actually exist.

Answer (score 4):

I tried console.log in some other project and collected all possible language codes, useful in speech to text and text to speech applications.

language code is ​"de-DE" for language ​" Deutsch"

language code is ​"en-US" for language ​" US English"

language code is ​"en-GB" for language ​" UK English Female"​

language code is ​"en-GB" for language ​" UK English Male"​

language code is ​"es-ES" for language ​" español"

language code is ​"es-US" for language ​" español de Estados Unidos"

language code is ​"fr-FR" for language ​" français"​

language code is ​"hi-IN" for language ​" हिन्दी Hindi"

language code is ​"id-ID" for language ​" Bahasa Indonesia"

language code is ​"it-IT" for language ​" italiano"

language code is ​"ja-JP" for language ​" 日本語"

language code is ​"ko-KR" for language ​" 한국의"

language code is ​"nl-NL" for language ​" Nederlands"

language code is ​"pl-PL" for language ​" polski"

language code is ​"pt-BR" for language ​" português do Brasil"

language code is ​"ru-RU" for language ​" русский"

language code is ​"zh-CN" for language ​" ​普通话（中国大陆）"

language code is ​"zh-HK" for language ​" ​粤語（香港）"

language code is ​"zh-TW" for language ​" 國語（臺灣）"

Happy Coding !